# C# WPF SQL Server Express local db ObjectContext.CreateDatabase yields error 26

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4, sql-server-2008r2-express

I've created a WPF app that utilizes SQL Server 2008 R2 Express as its backend. Using EF, I build my database by issuing a `Objectcontext.CreateDatabase()` method. This method (on some workstations) results in a SQL Server Error 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified.

My installation routine verifies the SQL Server Express dependency and installs accordingly.  My SQL Server Express default instance (`.\SQLEXPRESS`) is my target instance and is local to the machine running my app.

I'm able to login using SQL Server Management Studio using Windows Authentication and a server name of:

```
(local)\SQLEXPRESS, .\SQLEXPRESS, and CLASS8\SQLEXPRESS
```

All of these instance names work with SSMS, and I can issue commands inside SSMS with no issues. However, my app fails with error 26.

This setup works on my development workstation (Win 7 Pro), but fails in a VirtualBox running Win 7 Pro. I've gone through all the SQL Server settings and *think* I've got them configured identically.

The Windows Firewall has been disabled on my VirtualBox VM that is suffering this issue, so it shouldn't be a UDP packet being blocked...

What could be the cause of my problem?

**UPDATE**

Cleaning and rebuilding my project resolved this issue.